# A persistent compilation error when finding the maximum of three integers using java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm new to Java and trying to find a solution to a problem that has been returning a persistent compilation error.

I have pasted my code as below:

```
import java.util.*;

class MaxInteger {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        int num3 = sc.nextInt();
        int max = getMax(num1, num2, num3);

        System.out.println("Maximum input integer is " + max);
    }

    public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
        if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)) 
            return num1;
        else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3)) 
            return num2;
        else if ((num3 >= num1) && (num3 >= num2)) 
            return num3;
    }
}
```

edit: editing this question to make it better after seeing the responses that this may be viewed as off-topic.

1. The error message I'm getting is "missing return statement".
2. I understand that there is a Math.max method of finding the maximum, but in this particular case, the task was given to convert to "if else" statements.
3. There weren't any missing braces, brackets, and parentheses in my original code. They might have occurred in my copying of the code. Apologies for any confusion.

"tl;dr" version: 
Sorry for any mistakes, omissions or confusion caused by me.

Comment: Please format your code (your IDE should be able to do that for you) and always, always include the error that you're seeing as part of your question.

Comment: a hint: what would `getMax` return if none of these conditions would be fullfilled?

Comment: You have a missing closing class bracket.

Comment: The class isn't closed. A snippet of the error would greatly help here.

Comment: The best way to solve compilation error is to read the error message (and include it in the question) and look up what that error means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you know that this method will always return something, the compiler doesn't. The solution is to make the last `else if` an `else` as you know that this will still be logically correct.

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
    if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)) 
        return num1;
    else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3)) 
        return num2;
    return num3;
}
```

And one thing more! You're missing closing bracket of your class which I have added to your code snippet by editing the question as I qualified is as a typo. I assumed that you have it in your original code but I'm not sure now.

The above is about your compilation error. You can find some code review below.

Another thing is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ing your code. Why should you repeat something that some one has written before? To calculate maximum of three numbers simply return:

```
public static int maxOfThree(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
    return Math.max(Math.max(num1,num2),num3);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Math.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) returns the highest from two values. you can apply this operation twice to get max out of three

```
int max =  Math.max(Math.max(num1,num2),num3);
```

Comment: He's asking for solving compilation error, which above solution isn't.

Comment: It's not a solution to his problem.

Comment: @Stugal actually it is. SO acts like a compendium of solutions to a problem. The overall problem here is that he´s looking for the smallest number out of three. It just happens that he ran into a compiler error. But this question actually answers the problem which this question is based on.

Comment: It's not an answer.

Comment: @KevinEsche No it does not answer his problem, it shows simpler way of achieving what he already achieved with his code while still leaving him without answer to why his piece of code doesn't actually compile.

Comment: @Stugal I think let author decide which answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

This block:

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
    if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)) 
        return num1;
    else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3)) 
        return num2;
    else if ((num3 >= num1) && (num3 >= num2)) 
        return num3;
}
```

Requires an `else` statement with a return, or a return at the end of if/else block.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your compiler error appears to be that your `getMax()` method may not return a value in all cases.  Change your code to this for immediate relief:

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
    if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)) 
        return num1;
    else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3)) 
        return num2;
    // otherwise num3 must be the greatest
    else return num3;
}
```

Better yet, use my implementation or the answer given by @Amy for even better results.

Just for fun you could actually determine the max of the three numbers using a single ternary statement:

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int max = num1 > num2 ? (num1 > num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 > num3) ? num2 : num3;
    return max;
}
```

With regard to your current compiler error, the problem I saw is that you were missing a closing parenthesis around the class.  Your code should take this form:

```
class MaxInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        int num3 = sc.nextInt();
        int max = getMax(num1, num2, num3);

        System.out.println("Maximum input integer is " + max);
    }

    public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        int max = num1 > num2 ? (num1 > num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 > num3) ? num2 : num3;
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just realised I couldn't accept more than one correct answer. I upvoted your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your getMax method, compiler is telling you that you must always return a result. You should add a case which will execute when none of youre `if` clauses match - add it on the end or under an `else` block.

Comment: why downvote? This is correct. (Just avoid the term `case` since it refers to switch statements)

Answer (score 0):

The key point is making your paths easier to "read" by humans. That helps finding out why the compiler has a problem with your source code.

In your case: use **braces** for blocks. Always, even for one-liners, like in:

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) { 
  if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)) {
    return num1;
  } else {
    if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3)) {
      return num2;
    } else {
      if ((num3 >= num1) && (num3 >= num2)) {
      return num3;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, many people would say "there is a lot of 'line noise' now"; but the point is: isn't it much more obvious now that your final if ... doesn't have an else? In other words: there is a path through your method that doesn't contain a **return** statement. And you just didn't see that because of the way you wrote down/formatted/indented your code!

Thus, the key lessons here are:

1. Learn to read the compiler messages. They are really good in Java, and they are **to be trusted**!
2. Structure your code in a way that clearly shows the paths within your methods.
3. And of course, as others have correctly pointed out: don't re-invent the wheel. Java is coming with a **ton** of ready-to-use-well-tested libraries. Besides the learning effects, there is no sense in implementing your own min/max functionality.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
private static int getMax(int a, int b, int c) {
    int[] values = new int[]{a, b, c};
    Arrays.sort(values);
    return values[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections

```
public class MaxInteger {
 static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {        
      list.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    Collections.sort(list); // Sort the arraylist
    System.out.println("Maximum input integer is " + list.get(list.size() - 1));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 solution for finding max from any number of inputs:

```
public static int maxOf(int... num) {
    return Arrays.stream(num).max().getAsInt();
}
```